# How to make height of Gtk.StatusBar smaller in PyGObject (GTK+3)?

Tags: python, gtk, statusbar, pygobject

[Standart StatusBar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/278nf.png)
<-- So, here it how it looks in my application now. How can I make the height of it smaller? For e.g. in Google Chrome when you pointing some link it shows in the grey bar at the bottom of the page, I want same size.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is not using a `GtkStatusBar` (or any other GTK widgets, for that matter).

If you want to change the appearance of a GTK widgets, you'll have to either tweak the theme or use a custom widget, with your own sizing policy.

Comment: Chrome is just an example of which size I want. I found [here](http://python.zirael.org/e-gtk-statusbar1.html) that line self.status_bar.set_has_resize_grip(False) (#resize grip - small area in lower right corner for window resizing) can do what I need but only in GTK 2. So, no such function in 3?

Comment: There is no resize grip in GTK+ 3.x.